# Error while pip install discord for python

Tags: python

[Error Readings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpS4X.png)

I am try to code a Discord bot and I don't really know anything about coding. I cant seem to find many solutions for this anywhere. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste the error in a codeblock in your question instead of using a picture.

Comment: i had create a discord bot long back, maybe it can help you https://github.com/sahasrara62/discord_bot

Comment: It says Microsoft Visual C++ 14 is required, have you got that installed?

Comment: No I don't how do I get that

Comment: Got it now thanks for your help